# Rails Capybara Can't Sign In

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, devise

I have a spec as follows.

```
it 'should login with correct user/password', 
    js: true, driver: :selenium do

    visit new_user_session_path

    fill_in 'user_email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'user_password', with: user.password
    click_on 'loginButton'

    expect_current_path(home_path)

end
```

If I removed `driver: :selenium`, it works. I thought it's because of RSpec Configuration for transactions. Hence, I added Database Cleaner and disabled `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false`. However, it was still failing. I debugged Devise (devise-4.2.1/l
ib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb) as follows.

```
  def authenticate!
    resource  = password.present? && mapping.to.find_for_database_authentication(authentication_hash)
    hashed = false

    debugger
    if validate(resource){ hashed = true; resource.valid_password?(password) }
      remember_me(resource)
      resource.after_database_authentication
      success!(resource)
    end

    mapping.to.new.password = password if !hashed && Devise.paranoid
    fail(:not_found_in_database) unless resource
  end
```

After checking I can see `mapping.to.find_for_database_authentication(authentication_hash)` does return the user as wanted. However, `validate(resource)` failed for selenium ON. I checked more into it and found out `def self.compare(klass, hashed_password, password)` is the root cause (in devise-4.2.1/l
ib/devise/encryptor.rb).

So the main reason was because it couldn't compare the password. I suspect it has to do with Encryption. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After crazy time, I found the answer to this. The problem is with Capybara Selenium, it doesn't like number 3. Let me explain. My user.password was '12345678' and the code only fills in '1245678'

```
fill_in 'user_email', with: user.email
fill_in 'user_password', with: user.password
```

I've tried with different combinations such as '331', '123'. They all got the number 3 removed. Hence, I changed my test password to 'abcd' and it worked. Following is what I've got in my Gemfile.lock.

```
capybara (2.13.0)
rspec (3.6.0)
selenium-webdriver (3.4.3)
```